# How can I get the current Macbook's UUID from Objective-C?

Tags: macos, uuid

Does the SDK provide an API for retrieving the current Macbook's UUID?

Comment: I had an answer (something like "you're talking about a serial number?") and then quickly deleted it, when I realized that Macintoshes ***do*** have UUID's.  [There are definitely ways to get the UUID](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72355/how-to-get-uuid-with-python), but Apple makes it very hard to do this programatically.  Do you need the UUID of the MacBook, or just some unique identifier (e.g. the MacBook's MAC address from the Ethernet card)? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I know that Mac App Store Receipts use a combination of App bundle name, app version and MAC address so not even Apple use the UUID for something you would think ideal.

Answer (score 4):

So, if you don't care about the new AppStore rules etc... here you go:

```
- (NSString *)getSystemUUID {
    io_service_t platformExpert = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault,IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice"));
    if (!platformExpert)
        return nil;

    CFTypeRef serialNumberAsCFString = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(platformExpert,CFSTR(kIOPlatformUUIDKey),kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
    if (!serialNumberAsCFString)
        return nil;

    IOObjectRelease(platformExpert);
    return (__bridge NSString *)(serialNumberAsCFString);;
}
```

**Please Note:**

- You need to add `IOKit.framework` to your project in order for this
  to work.
- This code is ARC compliant;
- This code is safe and it will return a `nil` `NSString` if something goes wrong;
- Apple does not guarantee that all future systems will have a software-readable serial number.
- Developers should not make any assumptions about the
  format of the serial number such as its length or what characters it
  may contain.